# How to draw a rhombus with 45° angle with minimum movement?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

A segment of a line is given and a rhombus with 45° angle is told to construct within 7 elementary moves.
Circle and lines are elementary moves.

Comment: If this is a construction at euclidea.xyz, then you can find all of them on YouTube.

Comment: Ohh.... Thank you for your information....